# linux Bash - read contents of file , store them in a variable and create network config file

Tags: linux, bash

I got this file1.csv file which has lots of network interface data (approx 1000) and I have to create the network interface file , as in ifcfg-lo:x files.

the file1.csv file contents as follows:

```
Hostname        Loop_back_ip        netmask                    interface

localhost1     192.168.1.10         255.255.255.255         lo:116
```

So the script should read the contents from the file1.csv file and create interface file as :

file name = ifcfg-lo:116

File contents :

```
DEVICE=lo:116

IPADDR=192.168.1.10

NETMASK=255.255.255.255

NETWORK=192.168.1.0

BROADCAST=255.255.255.255

ONBOOT=yes

NAME=loopback
```

Comment: We're not going to do your work for you. What have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Start with reading the CSV file into a variable(array?) and then open network config file for writing and loop through each line item..  Write to file ..  Save.  Simple right?  Sorry for the ambiguity, however you question was just as ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks Zak for the direction. I am not good in programming so struggling with this, or else I wouldn't have asked this silly question here.

I created small script as follows:

while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a myArray

do

 echo ${myArray[0]}

 echo ${myArray[1]}

 echo ${myArray[2]}

done < file1.csv

Now I have to figure out how I can the array and create interface files

Comment: @Sail, note that you should edit your question to include the script you tried (instead of posting in the comments).

Comment: @AlexHowansky Start using this link: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried yesterday and I am very close to the solution. Researching the internet , I made a perl script and was able to create multiple interface by extracting data from csv file.

But there is small issue I see and not able to figure out why an extra character is coming in the file.

Following is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main
{
        # Note: this could be a full file path
        my $filename = "file1.csv";

        open(INPUT, $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename";

        # Read the header line.
        #my $line = <INPUT>;
        my $line;

        # Read the lines one by one.
        while($line = <INPUT>)
        {
                chomp($line);

                # Display the header, just to check things are working.

                my ($hostname, $ip, $netmask, $interface) = split(',', $line);
                print "$hostname $ip $netmask $interface\n";


                {
                        if( -d "/var/tmp/$hostname")
                        {
                                open(EF, ">/var/tmp/$hostname/ifcfg-$interface") or die "writing /var/tmp/$hostname/ifcfg-$interface\n";
                                print EF "DEVICE=$interface\n";
                                print EF "IPADDR=$ip\n";
                                print EF "NETMASK=$netmask\n";
                                print EF "NAME=loopback\n";
                                print EF "BOOTPROTO=none\n";
                                print EF "TYPE=Ethernet\n";
                                print EF "ONBOOT=yes\n";
                                close EF;
                        }
                        else
            {
                                system ("mkdir /var/tmp/$hostname");
                                open(EF, ">/var/tmp/$hostname/ifcfg-$interface") or die "writing /var/tmp/$hostname/ifcfg-$interface\n";
                                print EF "DEVICE=$interface\n";
                                print EF "IPADDR=$ip\n";
                                print EF "NETMASK=$netmask\n";
                                print EF "NAME=loopback\n";
                                print EF "BOOTPROTO=none\n";
                                print EF "TYPE=Ethernet\n";
                                print EF "ONBOOT=yes\n";
                                close EF;
                        }
                }

        }

        close(INPUT);
}

main();
```

So after executing the script it creates file as :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Jul 24 10:09 ifcfg-lo:20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Jul 24 10:09 ifcfg-lo:21
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Jul 24 10:09 ifcfg-lo:22
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 112 Jul 24 10:09 ifcfg-lo:23
```

When I "cat" the file for display it shows no issues:

```
$> cat ifcfg-lo:20
DEVICE=lo:20
IPADDR=A.B.C.D
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
NAME=loopback
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
```

But when I "vi" into the file then I see an extra character ( ^M) and I am able to figure out where it came from and its in every file I created:

```
$> vi ifcfg-lo:20

DEVICE=lo:20^M
IPADDR=A.B.C.D
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
NAME=loopback
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
```